# clash between xcolor and tikz

Tags: color

i can run this code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{styles_optique}
\begin{docuemnt}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\def \y {2};%demi hauteur de la lentille
\def \Ra {3};%rayon de la première face
\def \Rb {5};%rayon de la face de sortie
\def \anglea {asin(\y/\Ra)};
\def \angleb {asin(\y/\Rb)};
\def \ep {\Rb+\Ra-sqrt(\Rb*\Rb-\y*\y)-sqrt(\Ra*\Ra-\y*\y)};
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,\y);
\coordinate (A) at (0,-\y);
\coordinate (C1) at ({sqrt(\Ra*\Ra-\y*\y)},0);
\coordinate (C2) at ({-sqrt(\Rb*\Rb-\y*\y)},0);
\coordinate (S1) at ({sqrt(\Ra*\Ra-\y*\y)-\Ra},0);
\coordinate (S2) at ({\Rb-sqrt(\Rb*\Rb-\y*\y)},0);
\draw (C2)--(B) node[midway,fill=white]{$R_{2}$}--(A)--(C1)node[midway,fill=white]{$R_{1}$};
\draw[verre] (A) arc({180+\anglea}:{180-\anglea}:\Ra) arc({\angleb}:{-\angleb}:\Rb);
\draw[thin,->] (-5,0)--++(8,0)node[above]{\small axe optique};
\foreach \x/\xtex in {C1/$\mathrm{C_{1}}$,C2/$\mathrm{C_{2}}$,S1/$\mathrm{S_{1}}$,S2/$\mathrm{S_{2}}$}
\draw[shift={(\x)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\xtex};
\draw[shift={(S1)},|<->|] (0,20pt)--++({\ep},0) node[pos=0.5,above]{e};
\draw (0,-\y)node[above=20pt]{\small $n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but not when i insert it with these packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand{\textding}[1]{\text{\ding{#1}}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lastpage}
 \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multicol}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{chemist}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{on line,
  colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!33!white,
  boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=1pt,bottom=4pt}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\newtcolorbox{xp1}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!50!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}
\newtcolorbox{def1}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white,
colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=black,
coltitle=white,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.1in,xshift=0.15in},
                 boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,colframe=white,},
title=#2,#1}
\newtcolorbox{prop}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=black!2,
colframe=white!0!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!50!,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{blue}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Les lentilles minces convergentes}
\fancyhead[R]{Signaux}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\input{styles_optique}
\begin{document}
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand{\textding}[1]{\text{\ding{#1}}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lastpage}
 \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multicol}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{chemist}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{on line,
  colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!33!white,
  boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=1pt,bottom=4pt}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\newtcolorbox{xp1}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!50!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}
\newtcolorbox{def1}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white,
colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=black,
coltitle=white,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.1in,xshift=0.15in},
                 boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,colframe=white,},
title=#2,#1}
\newtcolorbox{prop}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=black!2,
colframe=white!0!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!50!,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{blue}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Les lentilles minces convergentes}
\fancyhead[R]{Signaux}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{Lycée JP Timbaud}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{2nd}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\input{styles_optique}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
```

here is style optique.tex :

```
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,patterns,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{fp}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}



%------ styles tikz ---------------
\tikzset{>=stealth,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,}
\tikzset{tiret/.style={gray,dashed}}
\tikzset{doublefleche/.style={|<->|,>=stealth,thin}}
\tikzset{bloc/.style={rounded corners=4pt,color=white,ball color=purple,smooth}}
\tikzset{force/.style={->,ultra thick,rounded corners=4pt,color=blue,smooth,line cap=round}}
\tikzset{vecteur/.style={->,thick,color=black,smooth}}
\tikzset{verre/.style={draw=SkyBlue,fill=SkyBlue!30}}
\tikzset{axis/.style={thin,gray}}
\tikzset{figure/.style={thick,color=#1,fill=purple, opacity=0.5}}
\tikzset{ressort/.style={very thick,black,smooth}}
\tikzset{eau/.style={draw=black,fill=blue,opacity=0.5}}
%-----------------------------------
% Commande \oeil 
\newcommand{\oeil}[1][] % rouge par dÈfaut 
{
\draw[#1,thick,rounded corners] (-15:1)--(0,0)--(15:1);
\draw[#1] (-15:0.8) arc (-15:15:0.8);
\draw[#1,fill=black] (0:0.75) ellipse(0.05 and 0.1);
} 

% \photon{options}{nombre}{énergie} symbole du photon centré en (0,0)
\newcommand{\photon}[3]%
    {
    \draw[#1] (-0.5,0) node {\tiny $\bullet$};
    \draw[#1,decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=2mm,amplitude=2mm},decorate] (-0.5,0)--++(1,0)node[midway,above=3mm]{#2};
    \draw[#1,->](0.5,0)--++(0.2,0)node[right]{#3};
    }
\newcommand{\photongauche}[3]%
    {
    \draw[#1] (0.5,0) node {\tiny $\bullet$};
    \draw[#1,decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=2mm,amplitude=2mm},decorate] (0.5,0)--++(-1,0)node[midway,above=3mm]{#2};
    \draw[#1,->](-0.5,0)--++(-0.2,0)node[left]{#3};
    }
% Commande \collimateur : collimateur1cmx3cm centré sur la fente d'entrée 
\newcommand{\collimateur}[1] 
{
\draw[#1,thick,|-|](0,0.1)--++(0,0.4)--++(3,0)--++(0,-1)--++(-3,0)--++(0,0.4);
\draw[#1,<->,>=latex](2.8,-0.5)--++(0,1);
} 
% commande \lunette : lunette 4x1cm centrée surle réticule.
\newcommand{\lunette}[1] 
{
\draw[#1,dashed](-1,0)--(4,0);
\draw[#1,dashed](0,-0.4)--++(0,0.8);
\draw[#1,gray, thick](-0.4,-0.45)--++(0.8,0);
\draw[#1,gray, thick](-0.4,0.45)--++(0.8,0);
\draw[#1,ultra thick](-1,-0.4)--++(0.8,0);
\draw[#1,ultra thick](-1,0.4)--++(0.8,0);
\draw[#1,ultra thick](0.2,-0.5)--++(2.8,0);
\draw[#1,ultra thick](0.2,0.5)--++(2.8,0);
\draw[#1,<->,>=latex](2.8,-0.5)--++(0,1);
\draw[#1,<->,>=latex](-0.8,-0.4)--++(0,0.8);
} 
% commande \prisme{position}{background}.
\newcommand{\prisme}[2] 
{
\draw[#1,#2](60:1)--(180:1)--(300:1)--cycle;
\draw[#1](60:1)--(-60:1);
}
```

Comment: I think that's probably because you call xcolor twice.

Comment: i have removed the double, but same problem. I even tried to remove xcolor and \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

Comment: @Plergux Not exactly. It's because the second time the package was loaded, it was loaded with an option that was not used the first time. So `\usepackage[table]{xcolor} \usepackage{xcolor}` works, but `\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage[table]{xcolor} ` does not, because `table` was not among the options used the first time.

Comment: As tikz also loads `xcolor`, load its options as document class options.

Comment: Did you double paste your code by accident, or did your original code contain two `\documentclass` statements? Also, I suspect that whatever goes into the file `styles_optique` is important: presumably that file loads TikZ? There could be further conflicts/clashes if you do it like that.

Comment: @yousben You seem to have added the preamble twice in your document. Anyways, the problem probably lies in the file `styles_optique.tex` (which you haven't shown us), without that it works fine here.

Comment: when i use `\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor} ` and i delet  ` \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  `:, it work, but i lose all my layout. I have big character , i dont like the final result for my document. Sorry for my very bad english :(

Comment: i add styles_optique.tex in my post. Thank you

Comment: Your file should compile if your first time loading `xcolor` you pass it all the required options, this means that the first time you should load `\usepackage[table, xcdraw,usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}`; however, there are some packages that you load that I don't have (such as `bclogo`), so I cannot test for sure.

Comment: Also, do you really need `pst-all` AND `TikZ` in the same document?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ah, I see. I was under the impression that calling the same thing twice was a no-no no matter what. Live and learn.

Comment: I use  `\usepackage[table, xcdraw,usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}` and i delet` pst-all, `now i have clash with  '\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}' . In this document i don't need bclogo

Comment: styles optique :[link](https://fr.overleaf.com/read/spyhrvhvkngh)

Comment: Your second code example is still a bit of a mess, it seems to have the same preamble twice. But if I take that example, remove one of the preambles, and then change `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}` to `\usepackage[table,xcdraw,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` it compiles without error.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it works but i lose my layout. I think the problem it is from styles_optique. my document no longer displays sections or sub-sections. and everything is displayed roughly as separate cards

Comment: Try removing `\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview} \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} \setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt} ` from `stylel_optique`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yeees !!! Thank you very much!!